# Parsing XML and replacing specific elements or attribute values via shell script

Tags: bash, shell, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet, xmllint

For the below xml ,I need to replace `<studentStatus>` for `<studentName>CLASSA</studentName>` to `<studentStatus>failed</studentStatus>`.

```
<studentFile>
    <student>
        <studentName>CLASSA</studentName>
        <studentStatus>Success</studentStatus>
        <studentActions>
            <studentAction>
                <studentType>Juniour</studentType>
                <studentStatus>Completed</studentStatus>
                <studentMsg/>
            </studentAction>
            <studentAction>
                <studentType>HighSchool</studentType>
                <studentStatus>Completed</studentStatus>
                <studentMsg/>
            </studentAction>
        </studentActions>
    </student>
    <student>
        <studentName>CLASSB</studentName>
        <studentStatus>Success</studentStatus>
        <studentActions>
            <studentAction>
                <studentType>Senior</studentType>
                <studentStatus>Completed</studentStatus>
            </studentAction>
            <studentAction>
                <studentType>Middle</studentType>
                <studentStatus>Completed</studentStatus>
            </studentAction>                         
        </studentActions>
    </student>
</studentFile>
```

What I got so far,

```
xmllint -xpath "/studentFile/student[studentName='CLASSA']/studentActions/studentAction[studentType="Juniour"]/studentStatus" myxml.xml
```

now i got the status of the student as Completed , now this value should be changed to Failed . Only for `<studentType>Juniour</studentType>`.
How should I edit the xml inorder to get it as ,

```
<studentFile>
    <student>
        <studentName>CLASSA</studentName>
        <studentStatus>Success</studentStatus>
        <studentActions>
            <studentAction>
                <studentType>Juniour</studentType>
                <studentStatus>Failed</studentStatus>
                <studentMsg/>
            </studentAction>
            <studentAction>
                <studentType>HighSchool</studentType>
                <studentStatus>Completed</studentStatus>
                <studentMsg/>
            </studentAction>
        </studentActions>
    </student>
    <student>
        <studentName>CLASSB</studentName>
        <studentStatus>Success</studentStatus>
        <studentActions>
            <studentAction>
                <studentType>Senior</studentType>
                <studentStatus>Completed</studentStatus>
            </studentAction>
            <studentAction>
                <studentType>Middle</studentType>
                <studentStatus>Completed</studentStatus>
            </studentAction>                         
        </studentActions>
    </student>
</studentFile>
```

Can this be done using sed. I know there are tools like xsltproc but not sure if this is installed in all nodes in our cluster .

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*Can this be done using sed.*" See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3016153 (applies to XML just as well).

Comment: Do you have access to `xmlstarlet`?

Comment: Pretty sure python comes with a xml module on most systems, could try that.

Comment: Your file is no valid XML. At least one `</student>` is missing.

Comment: @Cyrus edited now . I checked for xmlstarlet.
 `xmlstarlet`
`-bash: xmlstarlet: command not found`

Comment: @Neethu, and you have no privileges to install anything? xmlstarlet would be a good tool for further xml processing.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yeah from the below answers , using xmlstarlet is the easiest way. 
Let me check with the admin teams . Do you know any sed way to updating the xml?

Comment: @Neethu, xmlstarlet would be a good tool for further xml processing. And if xmlstarlet installation will be refused, we may look forward Python solution (you'll need to tell your Python version in that case)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Update value with `xmllint` in `file.xml`:

```
xmllint --shell file.xml << EOF
cd /studentFile/student[studentName='CLASSA']/studentActions/studentAction[studentType='Juniour']/studentStatus
set failed
save
EOF
```

or without [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
echo -e "cd /studentFile/student[studentName='CLASSA']/studentActions/studentAction[studentType='Juniour']/studentStatus\nset failed\nsave" | xmllint --shell file.xml
```

---

Update: With bash and XML in a variable:

```
xml=$(xmllint --shell <(echo "$xml") << EOF
cd /studentFile/student[studentName='CLASSA']/studentActions/studentAction[studentType='Juniour']/studentStatus
set failed
save -
EOF
)
```

or without here document:

```
xml=$(echo -e "cd /studentFile/student[studentName='CLASSA']/studentActions/studentAction[studentType='Juniour']/studentStatus\nset failed\nsave -" | xmllint --shell <(echo "$xml"))
```

Comment: if my xml is in a variable , how can this command be modified?

Comment: Hi @Cyrus ,
I tried adding  xml=$(xmllint --shell <(echo "$xml") << EOF
cd /studentFile/student[studentName='CLASSA']/studentActions/studentAction[studentType='Juniour']/studentStatus
set failed
save -
EOF
)

to my script but it says:

unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)' , should i enclose them in quotes ?

Comment: Hi Cyrus, For an xml tag that looks like < studentStatus/> , this command is not working . xml=$(echo -e "cd /studentFile/student[studentName='CLASSA']/studentActions/st‌​udentAction[studentT‌​ype='Juniour']/stude‌​ntStatus\nset failed\nsave -" | xmllint --shell <(echo "$xml")) ,it says `/studentFile/student[studentName='CLASSA']/studentActions/st‌​udentAction[studentT‌​ype='Juniour']/stude‌​ntStatus is an empty Node Set`, Can this command be modified in any way?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not reproduce this.

Comment: Just found a  workaround for this, i stored the  new xml node schema in a variable , update it using xmllint and then replaced it via sed. 
Thanks Cyrus for the help

Answer (score 3):

In case if [***xmlstarlet***](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) (a command line toolkit to query/edit/check/transform
XML documents) is accessible:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//studentAction/studentStatus[preceding-sibling::studentType[1][text() = 'Juniour'] \
           and ancestor::student/studentName[text() = 'CLASSA']]" -v failed students.xml
```

---

The above will output the initial XML document with needed replacement

---

The command details:

`ed -u` - edit/update mode

`//studentAction/studentStatus` - xpath expression to select `studentStatus` element which has:

- `preceding-sibling::studentType[1][text() = 'Juniour']` - preceding sibling element `studentType` with value `Juniour`
- `ancestor::student/studentName[text() = 'CLASSA']` - nearest element `studentName` with value `CLASSA`

Comment: Not sure the point of this answer, they say in the comments it isn't...

Comment: @123, that's pretty sad. Missed that comment while preparing the anser

Comment: The comment they just added makes it seem like it probably will be a useful answer, so not too sad

Comment: @123, the sad fact is that someone's unable to install such useful tools

Answer (score 3):

`xlmlint`, as the name implies, is for parsing and validating XML, not editing it. If you can install `xmlstarlet` on your cluster, you can do the following:

```
xmlstarlet ed --update "/studentFile/student[studentName='CLASSA']/studentActions/studentAction[studentType='Juniour']/studentStatus" --value "Failed" *file*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try my [Xembly](https://github.com/yegor256/xembly-gem) command-line tool:

```
$ xembly --xml file.xml 'XPATH "/studentFile/student[studentName=\'CLASSA\']/studentActions/studentAction[studentType=\'Juniour\']/studentStatus"; SET "failed";'
```

The full syntax of Xembly is [here](https://www.xembly.org).

Answer (score 0):

Update your xml file through xmllint with `--shell`.

```
$ xmllint --shell pom.xml
$ cd //*[local-name()='project']/*[local-name()='parent']/*[local-name()='version']
$ set 1.0.0
$ save
$ quit
```

You can combile bash with:

```
xml=$(xmllint --shell pom.xml <<EOF
cd //*[local-name()='project']/*[local-name()='parent']/*[local-name()='version']
set 1.0.0
save -
EOF
)
```