# Modifying in line attribute in XML using xmllint

Tags: xml, xmllint

I'm trying to update the value of a field in a specific block but that value is in a wrapped attribute (not sure what the proper name should be), ie:
`<target_tag name="my_tag" default="value_to_update"/>`
rather than:
`<target_tag name="my_tag">value_to_update</target_tag>`

I've been searching how to this and it seems to be something like:

```
xmllint --shell my_file.xml << EOF
cd //target_tag[@name="my_tag"]/default
set new_value
save
EOF
```

but this would work if the XML was of the second kind. How can I access/update the wrapped attribute? I can't seem to find the answer...

Comment: This might help: [Parsing XML and replacing specific elements or attribute values via shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43967407/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close!
The `cd` shell command must refer to the `@default` attribute

```
xmllint --shell tmp.xml << EOF
cd //target_tag[@name="my_tag"]/@default
cat .
set new_value
save
bye
EOF

cat tmp.xml
```

Console output

```
/ > cd //target_tag[@name="my_tag"]/@default
default > cat .
 -------
 default="value_to_update"
default > set new_value
default > save
default > bye
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <target_tag name="my_tag" default="new_value"/>
</root>
```

`xmllint` version

```
xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20914
```

Comment: Ah nice, thank you! That works with the dummy file I posted but not with my actual file.
It looks like loading with the xpath works:
```xmllint --xpath "//target_tag[@name=\"my_tag\"]/@default" /tmp/tmp.xml```
but when I try the EOF approach, I get ```warning: failed to load external entity "tmp.xml"```

Comment: Nevermind, I'd accidentally typo'd the filename, thanks again!

Comment: Follow-up question, if you have any ideas there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77065040/how-to-prevent-xmllint-from-removing-whitespaces